# PHP - Pricing Tables - Price is FREE

Tags: php

i have Price tables with monthly and yearly costs but i need a price table there is for free access. If i set the Price to Zero i get an error coz the code cant read the zero price. Below the code snippet. thanks

```
<?php foreach ($Packages->getDataAs("Package") as $p): ?>
                    <div class="price">
                        <div class="price-content">
                            <div class="main-price">
                                <h1><?= format_price($p->get("monthly_price")) ?></h1>
                                <p><?= htmlchars($Settings->get("data.currency")) ?>/<?= __("per month") ?></p>
                            </div>

                            <p class="special-discount">
                                <?php
                                    $total = 12 * $p->get("monthly_price");
                                    $dif = $total - $p->get("annual_price");
                                    $save = $dif * 100 / $total;

                                    if ($save > 0) {
                                        echo __("Save %s when paid annualy", format_price($dif) . " " . htmlchars($Settings->get("data.currency")));
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </p>
```

Comment: _i get an error coz the code cant read the zero price..._ What does "cant read" mean? Edit: do you mean "division by zero"?

Comment: i get this error on my price table: Warning: Division by zero in /home/www/next/inc/themes/skin/views/sections/pricing.php on line 50

Comment: This is Line 50:    $save = $dif * 100 / $total;

Comment: easy..just need to think more than 1 second... `if($total > 0)...`

Comment: damn.... Thank you

Comment: You can use a ternary : `$save = ($total > 0) ? $dif * 100 / $total : 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this will solve your problem

```
$total = 12 * $p->get("monthly_price");
$dif = $total - $p->get("annual_price");
if($total > 0)  //Omits Divide by zero exception
   $save = $dif * 100 / $total;
else
   $save = 0;
```